# adding components before hamburger bootstrap4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a navbar in Bootstrap 4:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header class="row">
  <div class="w-100">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="p-2" id="menuLabel">MENU</span><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="../img/svg/stopa-logo.svg" width="120">
      </a>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav menu-margined-right">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Missions</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">We Support</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav lang-right">
        <li class="nav-link">
          <a class="nav-item" href="#">CZ</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-link">
          <a class="nav-item" href="#">EN</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

and I want to make that the language switch links will be before "MENU" burger, is this possible?:
[LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FD2jE.png)

Any ideas how I can do that? I haven't been able to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

- Make `ul` `absolute` and place it with `top` and `right` coordinates.
- Set both `ul` and `li`'s to `inline-block`.

Example below:

```css
ul.nav.navbar-nav.lang-right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 160px;
  top: 7px;
  display: inline-block;
}
li.nav-link {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.7/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<header class="row">
  <div class="w-100">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="p-2" id="menuLabel">MENU</span><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="../img/svg/stopa-logo.svg" width="120">
      </a>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav menu-margined-right">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Missions</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">We Support</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav lang-right">
        <li class="nav-link">
          <a class="nav-item" href="#">CZ</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-link">
          <a class="nav-item" href="#">EN</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```